# JS getElementsByClassName() doesn't work with multiple elements having same class

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Problem** : this is not working!!

**HTML**

```
<div id="circle1" class="circle"></div>
<div id="circle2" class="circle"></div>
<div id="circle3" class="circle"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var circle = document.getElementsByClassName('circle');
        circle.onmouseover = function(){  /* This is not working */
           document.write("Hovering over one of the element that contains circle class");
        }
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` provides a list. You need to iterate it (for loop) and assign the event to each element of it.

Comment: I'd say the dupe target is more of an answer to their problem than a dupe....

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
var circle = document.getElementsByClassName("circle");
for (i = 0; i < circle.length; i++) {
    circle[i].onmouseover = function(){  /* This is not working */
           document.write("Hovering over one of the element that contains circle class");
        }
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_getelementsbyclassname_loop

Comment: Works!!!!!! ;) humanity is alive Thanks!!!

Comment: please vote !!!

Comment: thanks.in the future,if the problem happens,please say to me.

Comment: There is no need for global variables here.

Comment: Mr.Lain.  Don't take care here!This is the correct code!